# Is there any library to implement flexible grid view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, grid

Actually I don't know the appropriate word.
What I meant was this visualization which is flexible with image width and height proportion.
(http://www.eecs.mit.edu/people/faculty-advisors)

Could you guys help me to implement this view?
I want to show some of images like this.

> Is there some library or sample code?
>   Is this implemented with jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [BOOTSTRAP](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html) is the best and fastest way to do what you want. Start learning! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways to attack this. One is with bootstrap's responsive css. See this fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tylergreen/9v296/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="grid" class="span9">
            ﻿<div class="span3">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://example.com/image1.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            ﻿<div class="span3">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://example.com/image2.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
            etc...
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The other way is to use a jQuery "dynamic grid" plugin like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html).